# ckan 2.3 problems with adding the example_template plugin

Tags: templates, customization, ckan

I am trying to customize a ckan 2.3 installation with a template.

I followed [this documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/847-new-theming-docs/theming/templates.html).

When I try to restart the ckan I get a whole bunch of error messages ending with

> "ImportError: No module named plugin"

I have not changed any of the files named in the error-messages.

What can I do to get a custom template running?

--- UPDATE ---

I am importing the template with

> ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view datastore example_theme

The ckan is started with

> paster serve --reload /etc/ckan/default/development.ini  (restarting the machine don't makes a difference)

compiling the template was no problem and gave no error

Comment: Without a sample of the code, which you can edit in your original question, I'm afraid there is no-one that can help you with this question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to run command under ckanext-plugindirectory

$ python setup.py develop

then

$ paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini

if it's not working

then rename your plugin in this line

entry_points='''
    [ckan.plugins]    **example_theme**=ckanext.example_theme.plugin:ExampleThemePlugin
''',

and then change your plugin name and add this name into your development.ini 
also make sure that you have run

$ python setup.py develop

then

$ paster serve /etc/ckan/default/development.ini