# How to create CKAN example_theme - it is not working

Tags: ckan

I am following the tutorial at http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.6.2/theming/templates.html

I, of course, installed this version 2.6.2 and have successfully completed  the default setup.

step6) When I run the command to serve: paster serve --reload /etc/ckan/default/development.ini

I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named plugin

I see a lot of people getting the same error, there must be a reason for that. see the link: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3146, [ckan 2.3 problems with adding the example_template plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542328/ckan-2-3-problems-with-adding-the-example-template-plugin)

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

complete stack trace:

```
> (default) root@videolan:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-example_theme# paster serve --reload /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
Starting subprocess with file monitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 284, in command
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/serve.py", line 329, in loadapp
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/__init__.py", line 45, in make_app
    load_environment(conf, app_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py", line 97, in load_environment
    p.load_all()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 139, in load_all
    load(*plugins)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 153, in load
    service = _get_service(plugin)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/plugins/core.py", line 255, in _get_service
    return plugin.load()(name=plugin_name)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2302, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is that the main ckan repository also has an ckanext/example_theme (which is uses in its tests) and it's finding that one. That one doesn't have a plugin.py in the usual place, hence the error.

The solution is to use a different name than "example_theme".

There are two solutions:

1. To convert an existing extension, you need to rename its "example_theme" directory, edit the path to it in setup.py's entry_points, and then run `python setup.py develop` again.
2. Upgrade to CKAN 2.7.X (or later) and recreate the extension again. If you have any .pyc files in your extension directories, delete them. Restart CKAN.